# Selection of row based on timings

Tags: mysql, sql

Data :

```
Record_No Entry Timings  and CARD_RATE_TIMINGS and Rate 
1         19:40:42             09:28:30           64.98
2         19:40:42             17:23:26           65.10
3.        19:40:42             20:25:13           66.10
```

The requirement is to select only 2nd record as entry timing is after card_rate_timing and 3 record should be ignored as card rate timing is greater than entry timing.

Entry Timings table name is RTI and card rate timings table name is RTH

Comment: not sure if the title of your question is related to your actual question, but if you're looking to grab the last row, there's a `LAST()` function you could use.

Comment: Hold on, so you have a JOIN table? Are you looking for the second record in JOIN table?

Comment: Table is joined based on reference no which was common between both the tables.

Comment: @SQLLerner even your first record satisfies your condition right? Then why do you need the second record specifically?

Comment: Requirement is to check the rate when a particular transactions is processed. When the transactions was processed @ 19:40:42 rate  applicable was 65.10

Comment: @SQLLerner its confusing. In your question you didn't mentioned anything about rate. Update your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.Record_No, a.Entry_Timings, a.CARD_RATE_TIMINGS FROM <YOUR TABLE NAME> AS a WHERE a.Entry Timings > a.CARD_RATE_TIMINGS
```

replace  with your table name.

If you want only one record set limit as below,

```
SELECT a.Record_No, a.Entry_Timings, a.CARD_RATE_TIMINGS FROM <YOUR TABLE NAME> AS a WHERE a.Entry Timings > a.CARD_RATE_TIMINGS LIMIT 0, 1
```

Comment: In first query two records will be selected i.e record no 2 and 3 .

Comment: @SQLLerner I hope record 1 and 2 will be selected?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using 'Record_No' as your index, to create a table containing both of the columns, you would need to use a join statement.

```
SELECT RTI.Record_No, RTI.ENTRY_TIMINGS, RTH.CARD_RATE_TIMINGS
FROM RTI
INNER JOIN RTH
ON RTI.Record_No=RTH.Record_No;
```

You could use the ON clause to add another condition that specifies the ENTRY_TIMINGS is greater than CARD_RATE_TIMINGS

```
ON RTI.Record_No=RTH.Record_No AND RTI.ENTRY_TIMINGS > RTH.CARD_RATE_TIMINGS
```

However, based on your data, this would select row 1 and row 2. You have to add more conditions to filter the data from here how you want it. For example, as the comments suggested, using the LAST() function and another select statement (with this one nested inside of the FROM) to select only the last row.